# python 3.7 single line for comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I have a code that looks like this:

```
x = ["hello","world","if"]
test = [len(word) for word in x if len(word)>4]
print(test)
```

in my original code "len" is much complicated function, is there a way to do the calcualtion of len only once?
in a traditional for loop it can be done like this:

```
test = []
for word in x:
   temp= len(word)
   if temp > 4:
   test.append(temp)
```

can you please advise how to achieve the same result without using a traditional for loop.

Thanks

Comment: did you overwrite the default `len`? As far as I know `len` is actually considered an `O(1)` computation. Also a "traditional for loop" is functionally the same as a list comprehension, which is really syntactic sugar

Comment: I would somehow memorize the results, there are no builtin ways that automatically do this work for you

Comment: sorry, I try to simplify things and it look like I make them more complicated, I don't use len in my case it some_function(word), so the code looks like this:
[some_function(word) for word in x if some_function(word)>4]

Comment: Its not much computationally heavy for function like len. But for heavy functions you can use something like `test = [z for z in [func(y) for y in x] if z>4]`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `:=` operator (in case of Python 3.8+):

```
def my_len(s):
    # ...other complicated computations...
    return len(s)

x = ["hello","world","if"]
test = [l for word in x if (l:=my_len(word))>4]
print(test)
```

---

Note: don't overwrite default built-in functions, in this case `len()`. Other functions may depend on it.